# How do I get the log file a program creates when running it with subprocess.call()?

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I work with Gaussian, which is a program for molecular geometry optimization, among other applications. Gaussian can take days to end a single optimization so I decided to make a program on Python to send me an e-mail when it finishes running. The e-mail sending I figured out. The problem is that Gaussian automatically generates a log file and a chk file, which contains the actual results of the process and by using `subprocess.call(['command'], shell=False)` both files are not generated.

I also tried to solve the problem with `os.system(command)`, which gives me the .log file and the .chk file, but the e-mail is sent without waiting for the optimization completion.

Another important thing, I have to run the entire process in the background, because as I said at the beginning it might take days to be over and I can't leave the terminal open that long.

Comment: Leaving the terminal open can be achieved with `screen`.  You need to read the generated files from disk and include them into your report email. The generation of log files does not depend on the calling method.

Comment: Well, I managed to solve the problem, I've been looking for the answer and my mistake was quite obvious. To run Gaussian on the terminal I use `$ g09 input.com &`, so it runs in bg. So that was the command I've been using on `subprocess.call(['command']` and `os.system(command)`. The problem was the `&`, somehow `os.system()` doesn't wait for the process to end with it. By not using `&`, it worked out. (Still can't use `subprocess.call()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> by using `subprocess.call(['command'], shell=False)` both files are not generated.

[Your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730837/how-do-i-get-the-log-file-a-program-creates-when-running-it-with-subprocess-call#comment61046543_36730837) suggests that you are trying to run `subprocess.call(['g09 input.com &'], shell=False)` that is wrong.

Your code should raise `FileNotFoundError`. If you don't see it; it means `stderr` is hidden. You should fix it (make sure that you can see the output of `sys.stderr.write('stderr\n')`). By default, `stderr` is not hidden i.e., the way you start your parent script is broken. To be able to disconnect from the session, try:

```
$ nohup python /path/to/your_script.py &>your_script.log &
```

or use `screen`, `tmux`.

`shell=False` (btw, it is default—no need to pass it explicitly) should hint strongly that `call()` function does not expect a shell command. And indeed, `subprocess.call()` accepts an executable and its parameters as a list instead—it does not run the shell:

```
subprocess.check_call(['g09', 'input.com', 'arg 2', 'etc'])
```

Note: `check_call()` raises an exception if `g09` returns with a non-zero exit code (it indicates an error usually).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to suggest that, I were using `command.split()` in order to give the command as a list.

Comment: @DanielWatanabe the  split alone won't help here. `g09` knows nothing about `&` (there is no shell to interpret `&`). You should have seen an error on `g09` start.

Comment: I understand that now, what I don't get is that it did run the command.
To test if it was running at the time I made an input that would give a specific error message after a few minutes, and I received that message, which for me was enough to say it runs but doesn't give me the log file expected

Comment: But thanks, now I understand why the "&" won't work and it was quite obvious. As I said in previous comments, I had managed to solve it with `os.system()`. Now I edited my script to use `subprocess.call()`cutting off the `&`and running the command in the terminal as `$ script.py input.com &` it works!